# Understanding finite morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:Y\to X$ be a surjective finite morphism between Noetherian schemes. The definition of a [finite morphisms](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WG) requires $f^\#_U:\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to \mathcal{O}_Y(f^{-1}(U))$ to be a finite ring homomorphism, for every **affine** open $U\subset X$.

> Does that imply $f^\#_U:\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to \mathcal{O}_Y(f^{-1}(U))$ is a finite ring homomorphism for an arbitrary open $U\subset X$, and in particular for $U=X$? If not, is there some mild conditions under which these homomorphism become finite?

References or counterexamples would be appreciated.

Comment: I imagine we can use projective space in some way here... For now let $k$ be a field and perhaps we can define a morphism to $\mathbb{P}_k^1$ which is *not* finite on the entire space (which is notably not affine). Will try to flesh this out in more detail later and potentially post an answer, but if you want to look for a place to start, I would go to projective space first as it's concrete enough to deal with and, again, not affine.